# MVC4 ValidationMessageFor

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I have a view which accesses the data annotations contained within the model using ValidationMessageFor, and works with no problems. However, instead of displaying the validation message besides the relevant control (as standard practice), I want to display the validation message when the user hovers over a validation warning icon.

I have managed to get this partly working, but it requires the control in question has focus prior to the user clicking the validation warning icon, otherwise it displays nothing. Is it possible to retrieve the validation message via jQuery?

Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "EmailRequiredErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Languages.Models.RegistrationValidateModel))]
[StringLength(60, ErrorMessageResourceName = "EmailStringLengthErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Languages.Models.RegistrationValidateModel))]
[Display(Name = "EmailDisplayName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Languages.Models.RegistrationValidateModel))]
[RegularExpression(@".+@.+\..+", ErrorMessageResourceName = "EmailInvalidRegularExpressionErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Languages.Models.RegistrationValidateModel))]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

View

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
```

Generated HTML

```
<input class="span12" data-val="true" data-val-length="You must enter an email address less than 60 characters long" data-val-length-max="60" data-val-regex="You must enter a valid email address" data-val-regex-pattern=".+@.+\..+" data-val-required="You must enter an email address1" id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="" />
```

...

```
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

Currently, after validation the hover fails to retrieve the error message

[image]

However, if you give the control focus and then click the validation warning icon it displays the message (albeit in a slightly different position):

[image]

Comment: This might help... http://stackoverflow.com/a/7674660/609176

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing the attribute with jQuery should work with no problem, no matter the control has the focus or not. Try

```
$("#Email").attr("data-val-required")
```

Comment: The problem with that is it pulls a specific validation message that may not have occurred. Ideally, I need a way of showing all errors that have occurred for a given control.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question properly. I wonder if you can use the jQuery selectors to access the previous element of the span that contains the validation message. When there is an error, the span  has a specific class, `"field-validation-error"`. Smth like `$(".field-validation-error ~ input").attr("data-val-required")`