# jQuery and asp.net validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

I have a web form that is I hope to be used as a signup form for my site.

I have added some asp.net validators that show a * if there is an error with the input. What I would really like to do is show an image next to the form field that shows either a red X or a green tick depending if the input meets requirements.

Next to each of my form fields I have a div element that has the background set to show the red cross.

What I believe I need to do is set the client side validation to run a JQuery function that will change the class of the div to one that shows the green tick if the validation is happy.

I'm not best sure how to go about this,

Could someone provide some pointers as to how it would be best for me to take this further.

Best wishes

James

Comment: this plugin is what you need, I like bootstrap framework is easy to use and allows you to reach what you want and much much more http://bootstrapvalidator.com/

Answer (score 0):

I hope you could get the idea from the reply here....

[ASP.net MVC validation highlight and icon on incorrect fields Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470929/asp-net-mvc-validation-highlight-and-icon-on-incorrect-fields-jquery?rq=1)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'll definitely keep in mind as I am new to this.